# Listview item's background with gradient in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I've got a problem, using gradient in background for listview's items inside fragment activity (using ABS).

So, first of all I've got a background, that is succesfully using in other application. It has a gradient from (r = g = b = 91) to (r = g = b = 81).

[image: bg]

And thats how it looks in simple activity:
[image]

And thats how it looks inside fragment activity:
[image]

At first I think that it is very big gradient and I did a gradient only for 2 points, from (r = g = b = 80) to (r = g = b = 78).

[image]

And thats what I gоt:

[image]

I'm still want to use gradients in listview's items backgrounds in order items not seemed to be plane.

**So, why I'm getting such terrible image, using gradient in backgrounds for listview items inside fragment?**

Comment: Try to use 9-patch gradient png

Comment: Are you testing on same phone? And are you using same version of Android for both?

Comment: Παύλος, I don't know if it will exectly help, but I tried to set as a background btn_keyboard_key_normal.9.png from android resources and gradients looks pretty good. But it's quite hard to use gradient in 9-patch resources.

Comment: Warpzit, yep, testing on a same phone. Android 2.3 only.

Comment: Not sure but I think the Imgur photos have been replaced