# Strange transperent separator in listview

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, android, android-listfragment

I've got a fragment with categories:

[image]

When one of the categories is pressed, a list with stories is opened. The fragment of categories is replaced by a fragment with list:

[image]

**And now is the main part.** As a background for listview items **I don't use 9-patch resource, because background has difficult texture, that can't be streched, but can be repeated**.

I set a divider to null and it's height to 0 (I did it either in code and xml).

```
mList.setDivider(null);
mList.setDividerHeight(0);
```

But when I press back button I saw a list with categories for a while in space between list items:

[image]

Then I try to do a red background 1 px height and set it to listview:

```
mList.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sep));
mList.setDividerHeight(1);
```

But got the same result:

[image]

**I try to use 9-patch resource and there is no such bug. How can I use NOT 9-patch resource (I've already explained a reason higher) and avoid this problem?**

Comment: maybe the background you are using have transparent pixels?

Comment: Are these screen shots from an emulator or device? Is the issue present on both?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem, yes, it was my fault and there was a transperent part in a top of a background 1 px height. And I'll explain why I did this mistake and ask such stupid question. Some time ago I had asked this question, about gradients in listview items backgrounds in Fragments, and there still no answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780178/listview-items-background-with-gradient-in-fragment And I have to use 9-patch images, as one of the users suggested. But the background is diffiuclt and can't be repeated, so I left and top of the 9-patch background transperent. Need new bg now(